# How to add and update the values in a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
A    B   C    D
----------------
1    2   3    4
3    4   3    2
2    3   9    8
1    1   5    5
3    4   6    7
```

A, B, C, and D are the columns. I want to add another column, E, and set values 
of E according to the values in column C.

My code has been:

```
ALTER TABLE Letters 
ADD E

UPDATE Letters
SET E = 0
WHERE C = 9
```

However, E is not found in the table when I try to update it. When I do:

```
select * from Letters
```

the column E shows up, but I cannot access E when use the set method.

Why is this so and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a GO; statement in between them.  When you try to run it all at once it treats it as a single batch. Thus, the table is not updated until the transaction is committed and that is not done till the entire script is completed.  The GO  commits the changes and the select then will see them.

```
ALTER TABLE Letters 
ADD E INT

GO;

UPDATE Letters
SET E = 0
WHERE C = 9
```